# Copy files from PC to iPad App Document Folder

Tags: c#, vb.net, ipad

I want to programmatically (c# or vb.net) copy files to an apps document folder on the iPad.  The app has file sharing turned on.

I have looked through the iTunes SDK, but haven't found anything that would seem to allow you to access an app.

There is an application called [DiskAid](http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid) that does this so I know it's possible.  I just don't know where to begin and I cannot seem to find much info.

If anyone has any info on where to look or what I would use to do this please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure how an application that copys music from an iPod to a PC answers my question.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Anyone at all have a solution?  Still need some direction.

Answer (score -1):

I would first suggest you enable the iPod to be used for external storage. This can be done through iTunes.

-Connect your iPod to your computer and open iTunes.

-Click on the iPod device in the iTunes source list on the left side of the screen.

-Click the Settings tab at the top of the screen.

-Under Settings, check the box that says "Enable disk use."

Then just use in C#:

```
File.Copy("Source File Here", "iPod Destination Here");
```

Comment: Enabling disk use is not available for iPads or iPhones, only some iPods...I wish it was that easy.  Still need to find a solution for this.  Thanks!